# OpenGL Only Works on Second Frame

Tags: c++, opengl, render

I'm using SFML, OpenGL and the VC++ compiler. When I render something, it only pops up correctly(?) at the second run. Here's my code:

```
void Renderer::initializeOpenGL() {
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glOrtho(0, 1024, 0, 576, 0, 1024);
}

void Renderer::drawWorld(World* world) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.F, 1.F, 1.F);
    std::vector<int> vertices;
    for(unsigned int x = 0; x < world->width; x++) {
        bool left = false, right = false;
        if(x == 0)
            left = true;
        else if(x == world->width -1)
            right = true;
        for(unsigned int z = 0; z < world->depth; z++) {
            bool front = false, back = false;
            if(z == 0)
                front = true;
            else if(z == world->depth -1)
                back = true;
            for(unsigned int y = 0; y < world->height; y++) {
                if(!world->blocks[x][z][y])
                    continue;
                if(left == true || !world->blocks[x-1][z][y]) {
                    vertices.push_back(x);
                    vertices.push_back(y);
                    vertices.push_back(z);

                    vertices.push_back(x);
                    vertices.push_back(y);
                    vertices.push_back(z+1);

                    vertices.push_back(x);
                    vertices.push_back(y+1);
                    vertices.push_back(z+1);

                    vertices.push_back(x);
                    vertices.push_back(y+1);
                    vertices.push_back(z);
                }
                if(right == true || !world->blocks[x+1][z][y]) {
                    vertices.push_back(x+1);
                    vertices.push_back(y);
                    vertices.push_back(z);

                    vertices.push_back(x+1);
                    vertices.push_back(y);
                    vertices.push_back(z+1);

                    vertices.push_back(x+1);
                    vertices.push_back(y+1);
                    vertices.push_back(z+1);

                    vertices.push_back(x+1);
                    vertices.push_back(y+1);
                    vertices.push_back(z);
                }

                if(front == true || !world->blocks[x][z-1][y]) {
                    vertices.push_back(x);
                    vertices.push_back(y);
                    vertices.push_back(z+1);

                    vertices.push_back(x+1);
                    vertices.push_back(y);
                    vertices.push_back(z+1);

                    vertices.push_back(x+1);
                    vertices.push_back(y+1);
                    vertices.push_back(z+1);

                    vertices.push_back(x);
                    vertices.push_back(y+1);
                    vertices.push_back(z+1);
                }
                if(back == true || !world->blocks[x][z+1][y]) {
                    vertices.push_back(x);
                    vertices.push_back(y);
                    vertices.push_back(z);

                    vertices.push_back(x+1);
                    vertices.push_back(y);
                    vertices.push_back(z);

                    vertices.push_back(x+1);
                    vertices.push_back(y+1);
                    vertices.push_back(z);

                    vertices.push_back(x);
                    vertices.push_back(y+1);
                    vertices.push_back(z);
                }

                if(y == 0 || !world->blocks[x][z][y-1]) {
                    vertices.push_back(x);
                    vertices.push_back(y);
                    vertices.push_back(z);

                    vertices.push_back(x+1);
                    vertices.push_back(y);
                    vertices.push_back(z);

                    vertices.push_back(x+1);
                    vertices.push_back(y);
                    vertices.push_back(z+1);

                    vertices.push_back(x);
                    vertices.push_back(y);
                    vertices.push_back(z+1);
                }
                if(y == world->height -1 || !world->blocks[x][z][y+1]) {
                    vertices.push_back(x);
                    vertices.push_back(y+1);
                    vertices.push_back(z);

                    vertices.push_back(x+1);
                    vertices.push_back(y+1);
                    vertices.push_back(z);

                    vertices.push_back(x+1);
                    vertices.push_back(y+1);
                    vertices.push_back(z+1);

                    vertices.push_back(x);
                    vertices.push_back(y+1);
                    vertices.push_back(z+1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_INT, 0, &vertices[0]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, vertices.size() /3);
    std::cout << "Vertices: " << vertices.size() << std::endl;
}
```

And here are my results: 
1st call of drawWorld: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqkBp.png
2nd call of drawWorld: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEGsQ.png

Obviously initializeOpenGL only gets called 1 time, before the 1st call. There are no OpenGL statements outside the code provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Apparently, as discussed through the comments of my answer my approach is wrong. What stands correct is what user derhass pointed out in the comments. Quoting from derhass:

> No. GL is a state machine. It does not matter how the states are set
>   when they are not used. For vertex array state, all that matters are
>   draw calls. You have to make sure that all arrays you need are enabled
>   and all that you don't need are disabled at the time of the draw call.
>   Actually, it is good practice to avoid unnecessary state changes.

**My wrong assumption which led to this update:**

```
void Renderer::initializeOpenGL() {
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glOrtho(0, 1024, 0, 576, 0, 1024);
}
```

glEnableClientState doesn't really work like this.
You need to enable the client state before the draw call and disable it after it.

So i see you missing `glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);` after your draw call.
Also remove `glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);` from your initializeOpenGL() function and put it inside your drawWorld function (edit: before your vertexpointer call).

It's possible this is causing your problem.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with enabling that vertex array once and never disabling it.

Comment: if that's true, it's definitely good to know, but i guess it should be used that way in terms of 'good practice', right?

Comment: No. GL is a state machine. It does not matter how the states are set when they are not used. For vertex array state, all that matters are draw calls. You have to make sure that all arrays you need are enabled and all that you don't need are disabled at the time of the draw call. Actually, it is good practice to **avoid** unnecessary state changes. What you are suggesting here is a typical example of cargo cult programming based on some tutorials/examples which work that way.

Comment: I agree with @derhass. You should put the comment into your answer. Please plink me later so I can remove my downvote.

Comment: It's only fair to do so. I just thought it wasn't in my hand to fix this. Thought mods would take over. I was the first to upvote his comment and the information he provided is usefull and not something you can find in most tutorials/examples out there as they don't seem to elaborate that deep. He did hurt my feelings a bit though. Just a tiny bit :)